# from this below entered code "submit" value is not get parsed?

Tags: php

From this below entered code "submit" value is not get parsed???

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php if($_REQUEST['edit']=="edit"){ echo "update";}  else {echo "submit";} ?>" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
```

Comment: So ? What is the problem here ?

Comment: i can't able to insert and update in one single form